# "It's up to you to make the call"

Tags: expressions

Where does the expression  '*make the call*' come from?

> We have the evidence but it's up to the jury to make the call.

Comment: My guess (which I can't confirm) is that this is another idiom taken from baseball, a reference to the umpire making the call (often connoting a difficult choice between two things), for example whether it's a ball or a strike.

Comment: Why then does the umpire use the expression make a call? Why call?

Comment: Is this actually an idiom? Call means to cry out, make noise, etc. in a literal or figurative sense in nearly all the definitions I found. In this case it's a formal pronouncement or decision.

Comment: @medica - "Make the call" refers to choosing a strategy, not something an umpire typically does.

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm woefully ignorant of most sports (well, all of them, I believe), so I can't comment. I did state it was a guess. I wonder why it was up voted?

Comment: @medica - I wonder why it was upvoted as well.  Makes no sense.

Comment: I wonder if the expression came about due to lack of technology. A referee would have to cry his decision out loud enough for everyone to hear from far away?

Answer (score 2):

**call** decision

a) [countable]: the decision made by a  referee in a sports game

*make a good/bad call*

> There may have been a few bad calls, but they're making them for a
>   reason.

b) [singular]   (informal): a decision

> Don't just say what you think I would like.   It's your call.

........

I think usage (b) derived from usage (a)

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/call_2

Comment: My first thought was that it came from sports but then I wondered why the word call was used. Call must have originally come from a phone call that needed to be made or a shout and then it began to be used in sports. That's my hypothesis anyways.

Comment: Probably when the referees make decision, they CALL the players to be in front of them??

Comment: Note that the #2 definition is the subject of this question.  And note that the use of the idiom (in the US) is with regard to choosing a strategy, so the #1 definition does not fit.

Answer (score 1):

I have always assumed that the reference is to American football, where the quarterback must "call the play" -- specify what pattern/strategy will be used by his team -- in the huddle that occurs before the offensive team initiates a "play" by having their "center" "snap" the ball.

In most cases the quarterback chooses the play himself (from a "playbook" of options), but in some cases the play to be used is signalled in by the coach on the sidelines, somewhat analogous to upper-level management directing the actions of the first-line manager.

The expression "make the call" is often used in business meetings to refer to choosing a strategy.  It's instructive to note that this usage is **not** analogous to a decision by a referee during/after a "play", since (except in the case of dysfunctional management) the "call" must be made early enough to affect the actions of the players on the team.